# Unity objects not rotating around pivot point

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

Suddenly, for some reason, objects in the unity editor started rotating around their center of gravity (at least that's what I think is going on) instead of their pivot point. I tried placing the object inside an empty object which would serve as the new pivot point, like usual,  but this did not change anything. Is this some setting or some updated feature? How can I stop it?

Comment: Try posting this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ As programmers here are less likely to have experience with a 3D game proggy.

Answer (score 27):

Check the pivot-setting of the editor

[image]

Comment: Can also be toggled with the Z key.