# Blender to Unity Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, blender

In blender I am creating a character in pieces like head, body, legs, arms.
I export them from blender as FBX and I set the individual pieces Origin to Geometry so it rotates how I would expect in blender.

The problem is in Unity it rotates on all axis around something? So if I were to change the object rotation manually or though code it would move positions because it is rotating around something. How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [adjusting your](https://answers.unity.com/questions/984944/move-gameobject-pivot.html) [pivot settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693362/unity-objects-not-rotating-around-pivot-point)?

Comment: My issue was I was Exporting the object when it wasnt in the center of the scene in blender

Comment: Ah, whoops! Hope it's fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

From central make it to pivot so that is moves on the pivot points.
[pivot and global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz90F.png)